# 'str' object does not support item assignment telnetlib

Tags: python, python-2.7, string-formatting, telnetlib

I am trying to use the telnet library in python to obtain information from a device.  However I have an error as listed above which gets thrown when I try to run my code.

> 'str' object does not support item assignment

```
 tn = telnetlib.Telnet(host)
    tn.expect([r".*ogin:.*", r".*sername:.*"])
    tn.write(username+"\n")
    tn.expect(r".*assword:.*")
    tn.write(password+"\n")
    tn.write("terminal length 0"+"\n")
    tn.write("show " + configType + "-config"+"\n")
    tn.write("exit"+"\n")
    output = tn.read_all()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the 4th line you are doing

```
tn.expect(r".*assword:.*")
```

But [`telnet.expect`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/telnetlib.html#telnetlib.Telnet.expect) only accepts `list`.

Comment: So I would need to basically put that in a list